# Is there a way to to use IF statements for exctracting a cell value if two other cells match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am currently trying to take information from an array of cells but only if they match two different rows, so basically I want to write an IF with an AND statement to return a value I think?

I tried writing this at first,

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2, $T:$T, 0)), "No Match", "Match")
```

which was successful in telling me the values do match, but then I also need to meet the condition of

```
=IF(ISERROR((MATCH(D1, $U:$U, 0)), "No Match", "Match")
```

I tried to combine these two formulas with an AND statement to see if it would show me a "Match" based on two criteria like this

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2, $T:$T, 0)), "No Match", "Match")AND(IF(ISERROR((MATCH(D1, $U:$U, 0)), "No Match", "Match")
```

but it would not work

in order to spit out a value in a another column, does anyone know how to use a double match? I can make the two work independent obviously, so then I tried to use a VLookup instead of the "Match" with an AND statement like this

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2, $T:$T, 0)), "No Match", AND(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D1, $U:$U, 0), "No Match", VLOOKUP(A2, $T:$V, 3,FALSE)))))
```

which didnt work, I realize my excel skills are not the best but logically in my mind it seems possible to meet two criteria of two different cells to spit out a value where the two previous are met. If anyone has ever done this I would love the help!

To summarize, essentially I want to look in this table to find where column A and column B have specific values and then show me the value of column C where the other two match

Comment: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2, $T:$T, 0)+MATCH(A2, $U:$U, 0)), "No Match", "Match")` ?

Comment: In Excel you don't write IF condition AND condition. You need to write IF(AND(condition1, conditon2), return true, return false)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have made life difficult for yourself:

This is what you want: (pseudocode)

```
=IF(C1 AND C2, "Match", "No Match")
```

... but you started with:

```
=IF(NOT(C1), "No Match", "Match")
```

So, as you see, you need to rewrite your `=IF()` formulae first, and then you can start:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2, $T:$T, 0)), "No Match", "Match") 
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D1, $U:$U, 0)), "No Match", "Match")
```

... should become:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2, $T:$T, 0))), "Match", "No Match") 
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(D1, $U:$U, 0))), "Match", "No Match")
```

Now you have this, you can combine both your conditions, but beware: in Excel formulae you don't write `C1 AND C2` but `AND(C1,C2)`, so you get:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2, $T:$T, 0))),
        NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(D1, $U:$U, 0)))), "Match", "No Match")
```

Good luck